# Why can I not reject the exclusion of a partition in Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine

I have a MacBook Air 11-inch Mid-2012 running OS X 10.8.2. I have an external hard drive connected via USB. The hard drive has two partitions: an HFS+ partition that I use for Time Machine and a NTFS partition that I use for storing large files that I don't want on my small internal hard drive.

(Side Note: I use NTFS because the drive may need to be shared directly with Windows machines at some point in the future as hardware comes and goes through my hands a lot. I use Tuxera NTFS to write to the NTFS partition with great success so far.)

When I open Time Machine, I see that the data storage partition is in the exclusion list (that partition is named "EXTERNAL"):

[image]

When I select the "EXTERNAL" partition and remove it from the exclusion list, there are no errors and the partition is gone. Also, I see that the estimated backup size has increased by the amount of used space on the "EXTERNAL" partition:

[image]

However after I click save and then open the "Options..." window again, I see that the "EXTERNAL" partition is still in the list of excluded partitions, exactly like in the first image.

Why can I not back this partition up with Time Machine? I have seen other Mac Users report that that they can backup one partition of a disk to another partition on the same disk, but it does not appear that I can. (My reasoning for doing this is that I'd like the local version control that Time Machine offers for quick restoration of accidentally deleted or modified files. I backup both the internal SSD as well as the "EXTERNAL" partition using CrashPlan for offsite data protection in the case of a full disk failure.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Time Machine is designed for HFS+ formatted volumes.

You might have luck with the [Paragon NTFS driver](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/index.html) but if the NTFS volume is case-sensitive and your normal mac partition is not, you will have problems backing both up to the same Time Machine volume.

You might be able to use [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com) to copy the contents of the NTFS volume to an image file but not a [bootable one](http://help.bombich.com/kb/troubleshooting/can-ccc-back-up-my-bootcamp-windows-partition).

Also check out this [blog](http://blog.digitalfeed.net/2012/04/06/choosing-a-file-system-for-an-external-drive-for-mac-and-windows-fat32-exfat-ntfs-and-hfs/) which talks about related NTFS issues.

Comment: I hadn't considered the filesystem choice as part of the potential problem. I'll look into it and get back to this.